# Magento 2: LayeredNavegation filters with incorrect price

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I have products that appear in the catalog view with the attribute "minimal_price" and the LayeredNavegation filters them for the "price" attribute. I want the filter to use the "minimal price" instead of price.

**Atributes of the product:**

```
[273]=> array(37) {
            ["entity_id"]=> string(3) "273"         
            ["price"]=> string(7) "59.9000"       
            ["final_price"]=> string(7) "59.9000" 
            ["minimal_price"]=> string(7) "49.5074" 
            ["min_price"]=> string(7) "59.9000" 
            ["max_price"]=> string(7) "59.9000" 
            ["tier_price"]=> string(7) "49.5074" 
}
```

**Filter:** (I have tried changing the value "price" to "minimal_price" but it doesn't work.)

```
$this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->addFieldToFilter(
        'price',
        ['from' => $from, 'to' => $to]
);
```

[image]

**How to change this?**